# `While` Not showing echo

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble with getting my echo showing up. i think there is a problem with the `while` but the table is in the mysql so it should work normally. This is my code

```
    <?php


$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT
            topic_id,
            topic_subject
        FROM
            topics
        WHERE
            topics.topic_id = :topid');
$sql->bindParam(':topid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->rowCount();



        if($result === FALSE){
            echo 'The topic could not be displayed, please try again later.';
        }
        elseif(count($result) === 0){
            echo 'This topic doesn&prime;t exist.';
        }
    else
        {
        while($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
            //display post data
            echo '<table class="topic" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</th>
                    </tr>'; ?>
```

the `while` should show up because the topic exists in mysql. When i'm using a`var_dump($sql->errorInfo());`
 it say's `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }`
The null is because i created the topic in mysql as a test.

Comment: So, what does the script display?

Comment: @alessandro1997 sounds weird but it shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $sql->rowCount();

elseif(count($result) === 0){
```

$result is being assigned a row count; but `count()` is designed to count the elements in an array. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
 If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.
```

I think all you need is:

```
elseif($result === 0){
```

What I think's happening is that there are no results from your query, but the call to `count()` isn't working. It's passing that check, and since there are no records to retrieve, it's not going into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`count($results) === 0` doesn't make any sense, as `$result` already contains an integer. Your SQL query returns 0 rows, but since `count(0)` is `1`, your script does not know what to do, because the situation is not covered.

Just change `count($results) === 0` with `$results === 0`, and proceed to figure out why the query does not return the expected rows.